# Build modifier not applicable in any mode

Tags: modifiers, interface, build-modifier

I am having a strange problem, in blenders 2d animation interface I can't apply the build modifier, it doesn't matter if I am in object mode, draw mode, or edit mode, other modifiers apply with not issue but the build modifier "apply" button remains greyed out no matter what I do.

I am not getting any error messages and am at a loss.

Comment: can you share screenshots